# (SystemJS) XHR error (404) loading https://unpkg.com

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have been getting the following error when compiling my app. It was working perfectly up until recently (no changes on my side). I have searched forums relating to RXJS directory changes and made fixes where possible but with every fix, i get another error :(.

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoBt5.png)

**Systemjs.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
System.config({
    paths: {
        'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'            
    },
    map: {
        'app': 'app',

        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',         //see------https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2971
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    packages: {
        'app': {
            main: '/Shop/Components/main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            meta: {
              './*.js': {
                loader: '/scripts/systemjs-angular-loader.js'
              }
            }
        },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs/operators': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    }
});
})(this);
```

**Main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { AppModules } from './AppModules.js';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModules)
    .then(success => console.log(`Bootstrap success`))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I am pointing my npm path to unpkg.com as this is more suitable for me rather than node_modules so any other suggestions/fixes for this error would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has similar issue's with Systemjs.config.js, the answer is to add the version number to your angular bundles.

Example:

```
'npm:@angular/module@x.x.x/bundles/xxxx.umd.js',
```

That worked for me if there is a dependency conflict.